# given n*(n+1) for integer n, efficiently find n

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer k, which is known to be of the form k = n * (n+1) for a positive integer n, I want to find the value n.  Mathematically, the solution is `n = (sqrt(1+4*k)-1)/2`, but implementing this directly requires converting intermediate values to float, and then converting back to integer.  For example, in Go, this can be [implemented as follows](https://play.golang.org/p/avpzEn6r2-L):

```
func NFromK(k int) int {
    return int((math.Sqrt(float64(1+4*k))-1)/2 + 0.5)
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?  Maybe the solution can be found using integer arithmetic only?

(In my application, k is the length of an array which stores the n+1 vertices of an n-dimensional simplex.)

Comment: For "more efficient", just do `sqrt` and then cast to int (rounding down). Alongside the four basic arithmetic operations, `sqrt` is one of the floating-point operations which always returns correctly-rounded answers according to the IEEE 754 spec. It is possible to do it with integer arithmetic only, but it won't be more efficient to do so.

Comment: You can find an integer square root using [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  Use the loop termination condition to decide if you want to round up or round down.  N-R converges rapidly for square root calculations, so runs quickly.

Comment: Do you have a limit on the size of `n` (or `k`)?  If you're using IEEE 754 binary64 floating point, and `n < 2^52`, and you have correctly-rounded integer-to-float and square root operations available (spelled `float` and `sqrt` respectively), then the integer part of `sqrt(float(n))` will give `k` reliably. Given that `k` is the length of an actual array, that's probably plenty good enough for your use-case.

Comment: @MarkDickinson k is a positive `int32`.

Comment: @jochen In that case, the integer part of `sqrt(float(k)` should reliably give `n`; even single-precision IEEE 754 floating-point would be enough. (Sorry, I got `n` and `k` the wrong way around in the previous comment.) But if you want to avoid the use of floating-point, a bog-standard integer square root algorithm would do it. You don't mention a target language, but for example in Python >= 3.8, you could simply use `n = math.isqrt(k)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this just with integers, but I doubt that it would be more efficient. You could try to find the largest n such that n*n < k, which could be done with a binary search of the space 1 - k/2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just using math.Sqrt() function like following:

```
   func NFromK(k float64) int {
        return int(math.Sqrt(k))
    }
```